# Dragging rows to Root Level using treetTable and jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, treetable

I've been using Ludo's great [jquery plugin treetable](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable), but have reached a limitation in their advanced example I can't figure out.

Basically, in the last example provided here -- http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/ -- they are illustrating using jQuery UI's draggable and droppable to enabled you to shift things around in the tree.

The limitation however, as far as I can test, is that you  can't drag things out to the root level. Here is the UI code from the example:

```
// Drag & Drop Example Code
  $("#example-advanced .file, #example-advanced .folder").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: .75,
    refreshPositions: true, // Performance?
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 300,
    scroll: true
  });

  $("#example-advanced .folder").each(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").droppable({
      accept: ".file, .folder",
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var droppedEl = ui.draggable.parents("tr");
        $("#example-advanced").treetable("move", droppedEl.data("ttId"), $(this).data("ttId"));
      },
      hoverClass: "accept",
      over: function(e, ui) {
        var droppedEl = ui.draggable.parents("tr");
        if(this != droppedEl[0] && !$(this).is(".expanded")) {
          $("#example-advanced").treetable("expandNode", $(this).data("ttId"));
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I've been trying to hack it for sometime but I'm new to the plugin and haven't accomplished this.

Comment: I think the easier way to do that is creat the root as a folder.

Comment: Do you mean just putting it all in one folder? I can't do that with my data unfortunately I don't think. Could you elaborate? Maybe I'm inferring wrongly

Comment: Yes, you create a "fake" folder to be the root. Lets say the id "0" and in your code you check if id = 0 there is no parent, so is in the root.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'm working on trying it now. If you post an answer with a working solution I'll gladly give you the accepted answer and an upvote!

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this ? I have faltered at the same issue.